# Remove duplicates rows based on duplicate column entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table and I would to remove duplicates based on entry of duplicate columns.

So, in the table below (Run Code Snippet) there duplicates in the 'createdon' field, 07/04/2022 15:39:40.0000000 and the 'Id' field.

Is there a way to remove duplicates based selected fields?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252" />
<title>Export Data</title>
<style type="text/css">
.h {
color:Black;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
}
table {
border-collapse:collapse;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:Silver;
padding:3px;
}
td {
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:Silver;
padding:3px;
}
.rh {
background-color:White;
vertical-align:Top;
color:Black;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
text-align:Left;
}
.rt {
background-color:White;
vertical-align:Top;
color:Black;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
text-align:Left;
}
</style>
</head>
<bodybgColor=White>
<p class="h"></p>
<table cellspacing="0">

<tr class="rh">
<td>Id</td>
<td>SinkCreatedOn</td>
<td>SinkModifiedOn</td>
<td>createdon</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>15/12/2022 14:02:51</td>
<td>15/12/2022 14:02:51</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>16/12/2022 18:30:59</td>
<td>16/12/2022 18:30:59</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>16/12/2022 18:55:04</td>
<td>16/12/2022 18:55:04</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>20/12/2022 16:26:45</td>
<td>20/12/2022 16:26:45</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>22/12/2022 17:27:45</td>
<td>22/12/2022 17:27:45</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rt">
<td>AC28CA8A-80B6-EC11-983F-0022480078D3</td>
<td>22/12/2022 17:57:48</td>
<td>22/12/2022 17:57:48</td>
<td>07/04/2022 15:39:40</td>
</tr>

</table>
<p class="h"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove duplicates" - there are no duplicate rows, what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: Please don't use a html snippet for sample data. [So] supports markdown tables, and better yet you can provide DDL and DML in a code fence.

Comment: Did a search for [`[tsql] remove duplicate rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+remove+duplicate+rows) return anything of value?

Comment: No one can read this. You're unlikely to get a good answer if you post your table information this way.

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn, thanks for reaching out. I thought all they have to do is click on 'Run code snippet' to see the table. Am I incorrect?

Comment: A lot of people are not able to use that feature. There is built-in support for table rendering in markdown/commonmark you should use instead. See your other recent question, where I edited the table, for an example of what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
with dups as ( 
   select * , row_number() over (partition by ID,CreatedOn order by SinkCreatedOn) rn
   from table1
) 

delete from dups where rn > 1
```

by changing the `order by` column/direction you can manage which row to keep